# Why would MIN() query be slower than ORDER BY X LIMIT 1?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, innodb

To start of, I have seen: [Why is MAX() 100 times slower than ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930331/why-is-max-100-times-slower-than-order-by-limit-1)

It looks like the same question, but the issue there is lack of indices. So let me clarify my case.

---

To generalize, I will simplify my two queries:

```
-- min:
SELECT min(id) FROM my_table WHERE s_time >= now() - INTERVAL 14 DAY;
-- exec time: ~0.260 s

-- order-limit:
SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE s_time >= now() - INTERVAL 14 DAY ORDER BY s_time, id LIMIT 1;
-- exec time: ~0.060 s
```

Here, `id` is the primary key, and `s_time` is an indexed timestamp.

Running `explain format=json`, shows that the difference between these two queries is that the order-limit version has an ordering_operation that says `using_filesort: false`. Both show same `query_cost` analysis.

Now, my understanding of this is that if the column is indexed, then it's ordered in a btree. And, that these indexed entries have information of pertaining primary key. Finding the first one (limit 1) should be a simple traversal of the btree, and quite quick.

However, performing `MIN(primary_key) FROM foo WHERE indexed_entry > bar`, should be handled in the same way. Is this simply a case of poor optimization by innoDb?

---

If using LIMIT has a special optimization case where analyzes memory requirements for the number of entries, and if possible uses a priority queue instead of quicksort, shouldn't `MIN()` be part of that same use case where it uses `LIMIT 1`?

---

`explain` differences:

**`min-case:`**

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "91987.68"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "my_table",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": [
        "s_time"
      ],
      "key": "s_time",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "s_time"
      ],
      "key_length": "4",
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 229128,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 229128,
      "filtered": "100.00",
      "using_index": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "46162.08",
        "eval_cost": "45825.60",
        "prefix_cost": "91987.68",
        "data_read_per_join": "104M"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "id",
        "s_time"
      ],
      "attached_condition": "(`db`.`my_table`.`s_time` >= <cache>((now() - interval 14 day)))"
    }
  }
}
```

**`order-limit`**

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "92215.71"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "my_table",
        "access_type": "range",
        "possible_keys": [
          "s_time"
        ],
        "key": "s_time",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "s_time"
        ],
        "key_length": "4",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 229696,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 229696,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "using_index": true,
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "46276.51",
          "eval_cost": "45939.20",
          "prefix_cost": "92215.71",
          "data_read_per_join": "105M"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "s_time"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "(`db`.`my_table`.`started_time` >= <cache>((now() - interval 14 day)))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Interesting related documentation: method `bool check_if_pq_applicable()` in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/8.0.0/filesort_8cc.html

> DESCRIPTION Given a query like this: SELECT ... FROM t ORDER BY a1,...,an LIMIT max_rows; This function tests whether a priority queue should be used to keep the result. Necessary conditions are:
>
> estimate that it is actually cheaper than merge-sort
>   enough memory to store the  records.

Comment: Wouldn't mind having downvote explained. If it should belong in dba, then just vote to close and leave it be.

Comment: Did you mix up your times? (`order by` (0.26s) > `min` (0.06s), but I assume it is vice versa). Apart from that: your queries do two completely different things (and can return different values): the first one takes the first date that fulfills the condition (via the index), then stops (limit). It can be the same as the `min` id (especially if you add your data in order), but might be any other id (that has a lower time than the `min` id has). The `min`-query starts with that same entry/id, but will then have to check every entry after that to see if there's a lower id (with greater time).

Comment: @Solarflare I did mix up the times. Thanks for spotting it. Fixed. As for your explanation, it does make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do different things, hence one has to work harder.

```
SELECT  min(id)
    FROM  my_table
    WHERE  s_time >= now() - INTERVAL 14 DAY;
```

Searches *all* of the items in the last two weeks to find the lowest `id`.  `INDEX(s_time, id)` will help some.

```
SELECT  id
    FROM  my_table
    WHERE  s_time >= now() - INTERVAL 14 DAY
    ORDER BY  s_time, id
    LIMIT  1;
```

If you have `INDEX(stime, id), then it will look at only one row -- the first one of 14 days ago.  No scan.  No checking to see if it is the smallest`id`.

Note:  If you have `PRIMARY KEY(id), INDEX(stime)`, then that index is effectively `(stime, id)`.

Since you *probably* inserted the rows in `stime` order, the results will *probably* be the same.  But the Optimizer has *no* way of knowing that.